# How do i use more than 100.000 dot?

Tags: c, montecarlo

I have made this Project it can calculate the Pi with the Monte-Carlo method, but if I use more than 100.000 dots it crashes. Does anyone know how to use like a 1.000.000 dots without crashing? I'm using the GNU compiler. I've tried with another compiler but I had the same problem.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dot;
    int dotC = 0;
    int dotS = 0;

    printf("How many dot do you want to use?: ");
    scanf("%d", &dot);

    float pi[dot];

    float x[dot];
    float y[dot];
    for (int i = 1; i < dot; i++) {
        x[i] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dot; i++) {
        y[i] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    float distance[dot];
    for (int i = 0; i < dot; ++i) {
        distance[i] = sqrt(pow(x[i], 2) + pow(y[i], 2));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dot; ++i) {
        if (distance[i] < 1) {
            dotC++;
        }
        dotS++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dot; ++i) {
        pi[i] = (float)dotC / (float)dotS * 4;
    }

    printf("approximation of PY is: ");

    printf("%f\n", pi[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You get a **stack overflow** because you allocate large arrays with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) exceeding the stack space available to your program.

You can fix the problem by allocating these from the heap with `malloc()` or `calloc()`, but you can simplify the algorithm by not using arrays at all:

- for each random dot, compute the distance and update the `dotC` and `dotS` counters. No need to store the values.
- the loop to initialize the `x` array should start at `0`. You have undefined behavior as you do not initialize `x[0]`.
- `dotS` is actually redundant as its final value is the same as `dot`.
- you should use `double` instead of `float` for increased precision.
- you should use a simple multiplication instead of the more costly `pow()` function.
- there is no need for `sqrt()` either: comparing the square of the distance to `1.0` gives the same result.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dots;
    int dotC = 0;

    printf("How many dots do you want to use?: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &dots) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
        double x = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        double y = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        if (x * x + y * y <= 1.0)
            dotC++;
    }
    printf("approximation of PI is: %.9f\n", 4 * (double)dotC / (double)dots);
    return 0;
}
```

On systems with slow floating point, you could change the `for` loop to use 64-bit integers and produce the same result:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
        long long x = rand();
        long long y = rand();
        if (x * x + y * y <= (long long)RAND_MAX * RAND_MAX)
            dotC++;
    }
```

This algorithm is really a benchmark of the pseudo random number generator, running it for 1 billion dots only produces 4 or 5 decimal places in 13 seconds on my old Macbook with the Apple libC. Integer or floating point versions run at the same speed on this CPU.

Comment: Seems we game to the same conclusion. Your version is slightly better, so cheers!

Comment: @dreamcrash: your cat is mesmerizing :)

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, unfortunately it is not my cat, I just found this picture 10 years ago, I also thought the cat look amazing :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamically allocated array, you should use malloc. Replace :

```
float *pi, *x, *y;
x = malloc(dot * sizeof(float));
if (x==NULL) {
    printf("no memory for x\n");
    exit(1);
}
y = malloc(dot * sizeof(float));
if (y==NULL) {
    printf("no memory for y\n");
    exit(1);
}
pi = malloc(dot * sizeof(float));
if (pi==NULL) {
    printf("no memory for pi\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

That would work, however, for big numbers, it would get out of memory. Perhaps you can calculate incremental? Why store all the calculation? Perhaps the algorithm is not clear enough to me, but I guess that should be possible...

I looked at your code again, and this seems to do the same:

```
int main(){
   srand(time(NULL));
   int dot;
   int dotC = 0;
   int dotS = 0;

   printf("How mmany dot do you want to use?: ");
   scanf("%d",&dot);

   float pi, x, y;
   for (int i = 0; i < dot ; i++){
      x = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
      y = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
      if (sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) < 1)
      {
          dotC++;
      }
      dotS++;
   }
   printf("approximation of PY is: %f\n", dotC / (float)dotS * 4);
}
```

Comment: Array size can be dynamic on initialization since C99 (they are called Variable Length Arrays), see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: @michaeldel Never too old to learn :-) However, I posted another version without all those arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overflowing the stack (hence this website name) with the dynamic array allocations (like `float distance[dot]`) when `dot` is too large. To solve this, you can either increase the stack size (but you will encounter the same issue with larger numbers) or allocate your arrays on the heap instead, eg.

```c
float * x = calloc(dot, sizeof(float));
float * y = calloc(dot, sizeof(float));

/* ... */

free(x);
free(y);
```

Checking `calloc` return values for `NULL` is usually recommended as well, see `man calloc`.

Comment: There are 2 more arrays to allocate: `distance` and `pi`, and the algorithm seems flawed too.

Comment: Yes, I just showed it for the two first arrays as illustration. There seems indeed to be other correctness-related issues in loop indexing, as well as useless computations.

Answer (score 0):

Well while the other answers are correct and more reasonable, you can always temporarily increase the `stack size limit` using the `ulimit` commands if you are on `UNIX`. This will allow for a few more decimals.

Get the currect stack size with `ulimit -s` or `ulimit -a` to get more info.

Then you can find the maximum size the stack can be by typing `ulimit -H -s` or `ulimit -H -a` for more info.

Finally you can set the stack size to the maximum by typing `ulimit -s maxsize`, maxsize is equal to the number you get when you type `ulimit -H -s` .

Stack size will reset to its default value when your terminate your shell.